# How do you make armor that changes attributes only in its armor slot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make customized armor with an attribute changed - specifically, iron boots that slow you down when you wear them but give a huge amount of armor too - but whenever I make it in the command block, I end up getting it with slowness in any possible slot; main hand, off hand, head, whatever. I want these boots to only slow you down and protect you when you wear them on your feet, how would I do that?

Comment: How does one wear iron boots on its head?

Comment: I've tried adding the attribute by itself, but it works when it's in any slot, as I said. And it's just what it says: When on head, when on body, when on legs, et cetera. And I even tried specifying which slot it has to be in to work. When all else failed, I tried using the /execute command to apply slowness and resistance, but that doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of this :

```
/testfor @p[r=10]{
  SelectedItem:{
    id:"minecraft:iron_boots",tag:{
      display:{
        Name:"mySpecialIronBoots"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return an output of the player is holding a specific item.

Then you could replace those boots with the ones you want them to have. (i dont know the specific code for it but example is for diamond sword.

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {
  ench:[{
    id:16,lvl:5
  },{
    id:19,lvl:2
  },{
    id:20,lvl:2
  },{
    id:21,lvl:3
  },{
    id:34,lvl:3
  },{
    id:70,lvl:1
  }
]}
```